# Can you please help me understand this exercise?

Tags: self-study, correlation, autocorrelation, covariance, autoregressive

[image]

In the photo above is the exercise I have to solve. I am in my first year at Statistics and the explanations we are given are lacking many things.

I know the autocorrelation function is $p_{k} = \large \frac{ \gamma_{k}(Y_{t})}{ \gamma_0(Y_{t})}$. I replace $Y_{t}$ in the equation above with $X_{t}-X_{t-1}$ but I am stuck there.

I would really appreciate your help!
Thank you!

Comment: ... also do you know why isn't my equations show in mathform?

Comment: This post needs the self study tag.

Comment: @Alex 1. The problem with your equations was that they needed `$` symbols around them, So where you had typed `Y_{t}` you needed `$Y_{t}$` for example (which then renders as $Y_{t}$). See item 2 in the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference#). ... ctd

Comment: ctd... 2. Questions like these (routine textbook-style questions of this sort) are treated differently (we offer hints and guidance -- see the [help/on-topic] under "homework" and the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)). We try to mark them with the `self-study` tag (this tag helps other users who are trying to find help on similar problems - enabling them to get the benefit of  hints on their work without just being presented with a complete answer, which would negate the benefit of solving it themself once they get over the present difficulty)... ctd

Comment: ctd... for your part, you should show some more of an attempt to your problem further, pursuing the relevant definitions and properties. In particular, I'll offer some hints that indicate what you should show some work on: (i) What do $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_k$ mean? (ii) what [basic properties of variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) and covariances do you know about that might be relevant in finding $\gamma_0(X_t-X_{t-1})$ and $\gamma_k(X_t-X_{t-1})$?

Comment: Please write a more informative title.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently this is a discrete time series and $h>0$.

I don't know what the subscript $k$ on $\gamma_k$ is for but, anyway, just use the bilinearity of covariance:

\begin{align} {\rm cov}(Y_t, Y_{t+h}) &= {\rm cov}(X_t - X_{t-1}, X_{t+h}-X_{t+h-1}) \\
&= {\rm cov}(X_t, X_{t+h}) - {\rm cov}(X_t, X_{t+h-1}) - {\rm cov}(X_{t-1}, X_{t+h}) + {\rm cov}(X_{t-1}, X_{t+h-1}) \\
&= \gamma_k(h) - \gamma_k(h-1) - \gamma_k(h+1) + \gamma_k(h) \\
&= 2 \gamma_k(h) - \gamma_k(h-1) + \gamma_k(h+1)  
\end{align}

If the stationary variance of $X_t$ is $\sigma^2$ then the variance of $Y_t$ is $2\sigma^2 - 2 \gamma_k(1)$ so divide through by that to get the correlation.

This was quick and dirty so check my work. Good luck.